# Не дать стороннему файлу загрузить себя в оперативную память

Tags: windows, автозагрузка

Здравствуйте! Скажите, есть ли возможность при запуске стороннего exe файла через Process.Start(); не дать загрузить себя в оперативную память?

---

Добавлено из комментария:

В общем есть исполняемый файл, при первом запуске он копирует себя в оперативную память, для автозагрузки из нее, поэтому его детектируют 2 антивируса, хотя файл таковым не является (вирустотал 0 из 61 показывает), а вот мои антивирусы детектят его при исполнении и пишут, что файл загрузил себя в оперативную память, я же, в свою очередь хочу запретить данному файлу загружать себя в оперативную память и запускать его только тогда, когда я этого хочу, а не при запуске системы

Comment: что означает термин «"зашить" себя в оперативную память»?

Comment: В общем есть исполняемый файл, при первом запуске он копирует себя в оперативную память, для автозагрузки из нее, поэтому его детектируют 2 антивируса, хотя файл таковым не является (вирустотал 0 из 61 показывает), а вот мои антивирусы детектят его при исполнении и пишут, что файл загрузил себя в оперативную память, я же, в свою очередь хочу запретить данному файлу загружать себя в оперативную память и запускать его только тогда, когда я этого хочу, а не при запуске системы

Comment: создай второй процесс запускаемый при запуске системы. когда надо он запустит первый. Поставь цифровую подпись

Comment: То есть вы хотите не дать программе запуститься? Потому что для запуска она должна оказаться в оперативной памяти.

Comment: хороший вопрос, несмотря на очевидность ответа, т.к. основы сейчас очень мало где рассказывают. Начинаю чувствовать себя средневековым алхимиком. а не инженером...

Comment: А может это ошибка молотка?

Comment: @Alex78191 сомневаюсь, скорее общая неосведомленность. Да и текст сообщений антивирусов порой вводит в ступор и не очень соответствует действительности.

Comment: Так неосведомленность и приводит к ошибке молотка https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy

Comment: @VladD вот только не очень понятно что с метками делать, к C# это не относится (в текущем виде), а куда корректно перенести я не очень понимаю. По идее администрирование и/или windows но не уверен

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ок, изучаем или вспоминаем мат.часть.

1. Для того чтобы "запустить" файл - его **необходимо** загрузить в оперативную память, чтобы процессор мог получить доступ к коду этого файла и начать исполнять, заложенную в файл, программу.
2. Оперативная память хранит данные только во время работы компьютера и является энергозависимой. Из этого следует, что загрузка файла в оперативную память не может служить для запуска файла при запуске системы. При запуске системы оперативная память пустая и заполняется в процессе запуска системы.
3. Если ваш файл попадает в список авто-запуска, это значит. что во время своей работы, программа создает необходимые записи в системе для последующей автоматической загрузки. Это может быть попытка записи в реестр, создание ярлыка в паке StartUp (Автозагрузка), попытка заменить уже прописанный в автозагрузку файл своей копией и т.д. Именно на эти действия и реагируют антивирусы, т.к. подобным поведением обладают многие вредоносные программы.
4. Последние версии Windows (начиная с Win7) добавляют альтернативный поток данных к файлам, загруженным из сети, для опознавания таковых. Это также привлекает внимание антивирусного ПО при анализе запускаемых программ.
5. Если файл не числится в списках опасных файлов популярных ресурсов, это не значит что он таковым не является.
6. Если антивирус X блокирует или удаляет некоторый файл - это не означает что файл действительно вредоносный, могут быть слишком строгие (или бестолковые) правила у антивируса и ложное срабатывание.

---

7. Также существует масса вполне легальных, с точки зрения безопасности, действий, которые не отслеживаются антивирусами, но активно используются вредоносным ПО. Например подмена пути в существующих ярлыках программ - что приводит к запуску соответствующих программ лично пользователем при выполнении обычных действий.

---

Если вы уверены в безопасности программы для вашей системы и данных, остается решить одну проблему - удалить файл из автозагрузки.

К сожалению запретить программе выполнять заложенный в нее алгоритм можно только изменив саму программу.

Для чистки списков авто-запуска есть различные средства, я предпочитаю CCleaner, чтобы не лазить по всем уголкам системы, вычищая ненужные мне записи. Также есть встроенная утилита **msconfig**.

Если делать руками или скриптом, то проверять надо следующие места:

- Пользовательская папка автозагрузки: 
  `C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` Доступа к папкам других пользователей система не предоставит. В некоторых случаях, даже администратору потребуется явно выдать себе доступ.
- Планировщик задач Windows
- Реестр

  ```
  системный список автозагрузки
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

  пользовательский список автозагрузки
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

  если пользователе много, то также:
  HKEY_USERS\<user SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
  ```
- Список установленных служб.

Из перечисленного, только доступ к реестру и установка и запуск службы могут вызывать особый интерес антивирусов, остальное - разрешенные обычному пользователю действия.

После выяснения куда и что ваша программа записывает, можно создать `*.BAT` файл для запуска, в котором после команды на запуск файла прописать команды, которые удалят файл из списков автозагрузки, в которых файл был обнаружен ранее.

Также можно включить программу в список исключений антивируса, если вы уверены в ее безопасности. Но без острой необходимости я этого делать не рекомендую по многим причинам.

Comment: Отличный пример того, как отличный ответ спасает посредственный вопрос.

Comment: У майкорсофта есть отличная утилита [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) для проверки всех возможных мест автозагрузки.